# making the output appear faster on the client browser

Tags: php, asp-classic, buffer, flush, output-buffering

When I process large records in a while loop and each iteration of the loop outputs some info for the screen, I always find myself looking at an old screen. All I see is the activity icon spinning - which indicates that the server is processing some data.

I'm not running into timeout issues cause I already got the `set_time_limit (3600);` at the top of the script. It's just the boring screen that worries me.

In ASP ( where I came from), I go response.flush and that takes care of the problem.
By the way, in ASP, I always turn the buffering on with response.buffer=true. In PHP, this is a highly debatable area, I still do not get a clear view whether ob should be turned on or off.

Here, I'm not turning on the `ob_start` buffering, the question is why isn't echo push the content to the browser?

What do you do to make the browser progressively gets the html chunks as the while loop in the server processes information?

Comment: Why not ob_start and then just call [ob_flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) regularly in your loop

Comment: tried exactly that. not a dent.

Answer (score 0):

disable output buffering, reduce the buffer size in your php.ini, use implicit flush or explicitly flush using `flush()`. But if you have to display a large amount of data its maybe a better idea to paginate your content or use a command line script when processing takes too much time.

Comment: as to the "reducing the buffer size in your php.ini", I rather not touch the php.ini. Can that be done at page level?

Comment: almost any value in php.ini can be modified in your current script by the ini_set function.